# SpringDataJPA save OneToOne relationship getting Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have USER(id) and CONTACT(user_id, first, last) table. CONTACT.user_id is the foreign key to USER table.

In User.java:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

//bi-directional one-to-one association to Contact
@OneToOne(mappedBy="user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)   
private Contact contact;
```

In Contact.java:

```
    @Id
//  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    private int userId;

//bi-directional one-to-one association to User
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "User_id")
private User user;
```

When I run userRepository.save(user), I am getting:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mysite`.`contact`, CONSTRAINT `fk_CONTACT_USER1` FOREIGN KEY (`USER_ID`) REFERENCES `user` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

What did I do wrong? Thanks!

Comment: can you show the part of your code which contains `userRepository.save(user)`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably your id generation strategy (provided you initialized the contact properly). 
The user object must be inserted to DB to have its id set, but at the same time the Contact needs this id to be valid object.
They both have to happen in the same transaction.

If you switch the logging level to fine for your JPA (in perstitance.xml), you will most likely see the sequence of inserting the user and contact but contact will have user_id 0.

So, a) make sure you explicit set user in your contact (as you said the relation is managed by Contact. b) Set contact on the user. c) persist (in one transaction).
Depending on your JPA implementation it may still not work (check the queries issued, most likely there will be insert on contact and then update). Change the genration strategy to  TABLE, with  TABLE JPA takes the next free ID, assignes it to the object and does the insert so it is "known" before the insert.