# SpringDataJPA save OneToOne relationship through primary/foreign key, object saved order

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, spring-data-jpa

I have USER(id) and CONTACT(user_id, first, last) table. CONTACT.user_id is the foreign key to USER table.

In User.java:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Contact contact;
```

in Contact.java

```
@Id
@Column(name="USER_ID")
private Integer userId;

@MapsId 
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "contact")
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
private User user;
```

I use userRepository.saveAndFlush(user) to save USER object. Since I am using USER.ID as the foreign key in CONTACT, I need to insert USER before CONTACT, but JPA is Inserting CONTACT first, it sees CONTACT as a member of USER. So I am getting a USER_ID can not be NULL error when inserting CONTACT. What should I do to fix this the order of insert? Or should I just avoid using OneToOne mapping by sharing the primary key at all?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [SpringDataJPA save OneToOne relationship getting Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683427/springdatajpa-save-onetoone-relationship-getting-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-ro)

Answer (score 2):

> I have USER(id) and CONTACT(id, first, last) table. **CONTACT.user_id is
>   the foreign key to USER table**.

By making this statement I would say that the relationship is then not then a one-to-one with shared primary Key. If this was the case the I would expect the table structure to be as below.

```
USER(id)
CONTACT(id, first, last)
```

As an alternative to using @OneToOne, you could consider using @SecondaryTable i.e. Map the User entity across both tables: this seems a more natural fit for the model.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Tables#Multiple_tables

Anyway, regardless of that, if you want to use the @OneToOne then Example Two of the API docs below give

> an example One-to-one association that assumes both the source and
>   target share the same primary key values.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html

Following this I would say the mappings should be as below:

```
public class User{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy ="user", cascade =CascadeType.ALL)
    private Contact contact;
}

public class Contact{

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
}
```

Comment: MapsId tells JPA that the value used in the referenced Contact instance's userId field should be used to set the value in the User.id attribute.  Sequencing would need to be placed on the Contact.userId field for this to work or it will always be null (unless manually set by the application)

Comment: The mappings I proposed were actually the wrong way round. I have tested the updated mappings without any issues on MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that you have the User.contact relationship set as the controlling relationship - you've marked the Contact.user relationship as both mappedBy the contact mapping as well as specifying a joinColumn which is wrong.  These settings on the Contact.user relationship conflict so only one can be used, and the mappedBy essentially states that the foreign key field is controlled by the User.contact relationship, forcing the insert order you are seeing.

Switching the mappings around will give you what you are looking for:

```
public class User{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Contact contact;
}

public class Contact{
    @Id
    private Integer userId;

    @MapsId 
    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    private User user;
}
```

The above mappings specify that the USER_ID is a foreign key to the User.ID field and will use this relationship for both User.contact and Contact.user relations.  The MapsId will allow the Contact.user relationship to also set the Contact.userId value for you once it is set within the referenced User instance.